# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException and IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception

Here the Exception is IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
     elements.add(10);
     int firstElmnt = elements.get(1);
     System.out.println(firstElmnt);
}
```

But here the Exception is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
     elements.add(10);
     int firstElmnt = elements.get(-1);
     System.out.println(firstElmnt);
}
```

Does that mean for negative numbers we get IndexOutOfBoundException?

Answer (score 4):

The Javadoc of `List` specifies that `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown:

> if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

Since `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a sub-class of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, implementations of the `List` interface can choose to throw that exception instead of the base `IndexOutOfBoundsException` class.

For positive index which is out of range, the exception is thrown by this code:

```
private void rangeCheck(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

On the other hand, for negative indices, the exception is thrown by accessing the backing array with a negative index:

```
E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

This saves the `ArrayList` implementation the need to explicitly check whether the index is negative.

Answer (score -7):

You're getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in the first code, because inside the implementation of `ArrayList` you have a array with a size of 10 and you are trying to get the second index of that array, this index is inside the array but you don't add any element on it.

The second is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are trying to get a index beyond the range of the array.